# Flowchart graph/map to visualize the interplay of different results

Tags: diagrams, graphs

Im trying to make overview graphs of my subjects. In the idea of flowcharts/mindmaps etc. where i want to visualize how different results interact with each other. I did a version with itkz-cd wich does not look particularly nice. It does the job and is flexible enough for what i need it for (and im a bit used to it).

My question is: do you guys know any alternatives for such a task? It does not have to be Tex based, but would be nice ofcourse!

Example (made with [tikzcd.yichuanshen.de](http://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de)):
[image]
Pls dont consider the details it is just a draft :)

**Edit**: I ended up using an only diagram editor (diagrameditor.com) because i just use this for myself, here some result.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There is an alternative: `pstricks`. Just do it with the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node`.

Comment: You can draw this also with `tikz`˛using libraries `matrix` ...

Comment: Any news? Does my answer provide acceptable solution?

Comment: @Zarko i think tex might be a bit cumbersom for graphical representation of ideas. your solution is probably one of the best and would look delightful if you had to finish something to present to other people. but for my own usage i decided on an online diagram editor (diagrameditor.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As starting point. By use of the `matrix` library from the `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 every path/.style = {-Straight Barb}
                        ] 
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes = {text width=6em, align=center, anchor=center, inner sep=1pt,
                      anchor=center, font=\small\linespread{0.84}\relax},
             column sep=11mm,
             row sep= 3mm
            ]
{
text two lines long
    &   &   &   text two lines long \\
%
    &   text two lines long
        &   text two lines long
            &   short text          \\
%
text two lines long
    &   &   text two lines long
            &   text two lines long \\
%
text two lines long
    &   text two lines long
        &   &   text two lines long \\
%
text two lines long
    &   very long text in three lines
        &   &                       \\
%
    &   &   text two lines long
            &                       \\
};
\draw   (m-2-2) edge (m-1-1)
        (m-3-1) edge (m-3-3)    (m-3-4) edge (m-3-3)
        (m-3-1) edge (m-1-1)
        (m-3-1) edge (m-4-2)    (m-3-4) edge (m-2-3)    
        (m-4-2) edge (m-2-2)    (m-4-2) edge (m-3-3)
        (m-4-1) edge (m-4-2)
        (m-3-3) edge (m-6-3)
        (m-5-1) edge (m-4-2)
        (m-5-1) edge (m-5-2)
        (m-5-1) edge[bend right=15] (m-6-3)
%
        (m-2-3) edge (m-1-4)
        (m-2-4) edge (m-1-4)    (m-2-4) edge (m-3-4)
        (m-4-4) edge (m-3-4)                     
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
correct image code (added lost part of code)